# What is the default log_format on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

How can I show the current `log_format` in Nginx?

I do not have it explicitly set (this shows nothing):

`grep -i 'log_format' *`

And my logging in the config is defined without a format parameter:

`access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;`

How can I make Nginx print the value of the current log format, or how can I find out what it is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Accoding to: https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html default log format is Combined. `If the format is not specified then the predefined “combined” format is used.`

Comment: not sure how I missed that

Comment: Worth to mention: `log_format` only applies to `access_log`. More information, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246756/is-it-possible-to-specify-custom-error-log-format-on-nginx

Comment: It would've been helpful to include the definition for log_format combined as that's what I was after.

Answer (score 15):

To expand on [Alexander's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/916655/948650), the definition of the default "combined" log format is given at the end of [log_format section](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format). At least for nginx 1.21 it is

```
log_format combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```