# Nginx access_log format "timing"?

Tags: nginx, logging, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using a [config snippet](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/configuring-nginx) to setup a reverse proxy with nginx version: nginx/1.14.1 - it has "timing" specified as access_log's format - that causes an error.

```
## Application specific logs
access_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.com-access.log timing;
error_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.com-error.log;
```

Here's what nginx -t says:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "timing" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf:27
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Might this be a feature of a newer nginx or the Plus version? Or does "timing" need to be defined somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for a `access_log` is a name for a pre-defined `log_format`. In most cases you can just omit this parameter and Nginx will use the default option which is "combined".

Look this at oficial reference of [access_log](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) or at this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/916653/what-is-the-default-log-format-on-nginx).